# Проблемы с добавлением google-аутентификации | Android-Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, аутентификация, firebase-android

Я пытаюсь добавить гугл аутентификацию при помощи firebase в свое android-приложение. Я так и не смог разобраться с ней самостоятельно, и потому использовал код который взял [здесь](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java). Разметку для активности я взял из этого же репозитория.

Но даже используя тот код у меня ничего не заработало. При отладке я увидел, что переменная `user=null` несмотря на то, что метод `signIn()` был вызван, google-аккаунт был выбран, но при этом всем `user = null`, как так? Я бы хотел увидеть простой пример google-аутентификации в андроид приложении, что бы даже мне было понятно.

**upd**

Настройки firebase:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код по ссылке:

```
public class GoogleSignInActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private TextView mDetailTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google);

        // Views
        mStatusTextView = findViewById(R.id.status);
        mDetailTextView = findViewById(R.id.detail);

        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        // [START config_signin]
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END config_signin]

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        // [START initialize_auth]
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]
    }

    // [START on_start_check_user]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }
    // [END on_start_check_user]

    // [START onactivityresult]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }
    }
    // [END onactivityresult]

    // [START auth_with_google]
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        showProgressDialog();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END auth_with_google]

    // [START signin]
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    // [END signin]

    private void signOut() {
        // Firebase sign out
        mAuth.signOut();

        // Google sign out
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
                new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void revokeAccess() {
        // Firebase sign out
        mAuth.signOut();

        // Google revoke access
        mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess().addOnCompleteListener(this,
                new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        if (user != null) {
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.google_status_fmt, user.getEmail()));
            mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
            mDetailTextView.setText(null);

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            signIn();
        } else if (i == R.id.sign_out_button) {
            signOut();
        } else if (i == R.id.disconnect_button) {
            revokeAccess();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите проблемный код прямо в вопросе. По ссылкам не все готовы ходить. Также покажите настройки на стороне Firebase- может у вас там чего-то не хватает

Comment: @ЮрийСПб настройки firebase сейчас приложу в вопрос, а по ссылке - код с github могу его также закопипастить в вопрос.

Comment: А google-services.json в проекте обновляли? Запускаете с подписью дебажным ключом? Его отпечаток в настройках приложения в Firebase указан?

Comment: google-services.json в проекте есть. Но что за дебажный ключ? Не очень понимаю

Comment: Приложения подписываются спец. ключом. По умолчанию - дебажным, в стор можно только с подписью релизным ключом. У вас в Firebase должно быть создано приложение для андроид где должны быть указаны отпечатки этих ключей. Их можно взять из студии, во вкладке gradle выполнив команду signin config. Всё это описано в документации

Comment: После добавления отпечатков google-services.json надо обновить. Лучше заменой содержимого, чем самого файла, ибо замена файла - глючит

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так. С google-services.json все понятно. С отпечатками вот нет. В настройках проекта в Firebase я нашел "Контрольные суммы сертификатов SHA" где был указан SHA ключ, если речь шла о нем то что делать с ним я не знаю

Comment: Так он там у вас указан? Вот так можно достать отпечаток ключа: https://imgur.com/gallery/k303gZL

Comment: Да, у меня он там указан. Что мне теперь с этим делать?

Comment: Указан тот же, что и студия выдаёт? Если да - то залоггируйте как-нибудь каждый шаг работы программы или дебаггером пройдитесь - без этого явным проблем в коде и настройках не видать.

Comment: Упс. Не проверил. Ключи разные. Получается теперь мне нужно удалить тот ключ из настроек в Firebase и создать новый из студии?

Comment: Либо удалить, либо добавить ешё один. И в студии вам его не создать надо, но отпечаток уже созданного и использующегося взять.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Сасибо большое, все работет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае проблема в том, что в настройках Firebase надо указать отпечатки ключей, которыми подписывается приложение. Взять их можно из студии, выполнив `gradle` команду `signingReport`, после чего надо заменить `google-services.json` файл в проекте.

[image: https://imgur.com/gallery/k303gZL]